# What's the index URL for Helm charts added to ACR?

Tags: kubernetes-helm, azure-container-registry, fluxcd

I'm following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-helm-repos) guide on how to "Push and pull Helm charts to an Azure container registry".

So I've pushed a chart to ACR. I can see that it's there, both via the Azure UI and

```
az acr repository show \
  --name mycontainerregistry \
  --repository helm/hello-world
```

Is there a repository URL that I can use to configure others (in this case Flux v2) to pull charts from? I thought it might be `https://mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/helm/v1/repo/index.yaml`, but it doesn't list the chart that I pushed.

What do I have to do to add my charts to the `index.yaml`, or should I use another URL?

**Edit**

I just realized that `https://mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/helm/v1/repo/index.yaml` will show the charts pushed via `az acr helm push` commands. So maybe that URL is something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, you can use the command `helm repo add` to add the Azure Container Registry as a repository to the helm, and then you can pull the charts from the ACR. And all the charts in the ACR named `myacr.azurecr.io/helm/chartname` and it means you will pull the charts from the ACR. The name decides where the chart pulls from.

For example, you add a repo with the command here:

```
helm repo add technosophos https://technosophos.github.io/tscharts
```

and you can show the repo like this:

[image]

then you can pull charts from this repo:

[image: helm pull]

You can do the things like this with ACR. And helm will help you update the index of the repo. You don't need to do it yourself.

Comment: I am struggling to get the proper helm repo URL of an azure container registry (ACR) ... Keeps telling me: `Error: looks like "https://XXX.azurecr.io/helm/v1/repo/YYY/" is not a valid chart repository or cannot be reached: failed to fetch https://XXX.azurecr.io/helm/v1/repo/YYY/index.yaml : 401 Unauthorized`

Comment: Even though this answer was selected as a solution it's not applicable. Adding an Azure Container Registry as a native repository in Helm will only work if the charts are pushed via "az acr helm push".

Answer (score 2):

I used the following command and it works:

```
helm repo add YOUR_ACR_NAME https://YOUR_ACR_NAME.azurecr.io/helm/v1/repo  --username YOUR_ACR_NAME --password YOUR_ACR_PASSWORD
```

The result will be something like:

```
"YOUR_ACR_NAME " has been added to your repositories
```

The problem is, after this I still cannot find all helm charts I added by "az acr helm push". So sad.